# Response hangs in Postman after returning a PDF with FileContentResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue with downloading a pdf file from an asp.net core web-api. After sending the post request, the application sends a response but the response body will not be transmitted completely. Although 200-status the time runs and the size stops at 289 B. The pdf is a byte array created by the ..Winforms.ReportViewer. The strange thing is, when I build a report with only embeded images the application works as well and I receive the full response but If I include code generated images such as qr-codes I run into the described issue. When I try to save the pdf file by the application localy it works as expected, but when I try read the pdf from the locally saved file and send the pdf with a response, I run also into the described issue. I have no idea why it's happens. Maybe someone have an idea.

This is my controller method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("client")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateReportByteArrayToClient([FromBody] ReportRequest request)
    {
        (int statuscode, string message) status = await _verificationService.Verify(request.device!, _context);
        if (status.statuscode != StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            return StatusCode(status.statuscode, status.message);

        string reportFilename = request.device!.Name + "_" + request.ReportFilename;
        reportFilename = FileUtility.AddTimeStampToFilename(reportFilename);
        reportFilename = $"{reportFilename}.pdf";
        ReportData reportData = _dataService.TakeData(request, _config);
        byte[] reportBytes = _reportService.CreateReportBytes(reportData, request.RDLCTemplate!, _config);

        var file = File(reportBytes, "application/pdf", reportFilename);
        return file;
    }
```

And here is a screenshot of the response in postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYggc.jpg)

thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean for `The pdf is a byte array created by the ..Winforms.ReportViewer.`? What is your `FileUtility`, `TakeData` method and `CreateReportBytes`?

Comment: Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", ...) returns a byte[]. I composed it into a Service _reportService with method CreateReportBytes. FileUtility appends a timestamp to the filename, TakeData reads data from the database for the rdlc report. But those lines are not producing the mentioned issue. I figured out that the Kestrels MaxResponseBufferSize is limited to 64 kB and my generated report is bigger than 64 kB. If I decrease the data for the rdlc report and the report is smaller than 64 kB than it works. Increase the MaxResponseBufferSize don't solve the issue